# Selecting Matching Features in shapefile

Tags: qgis, vector, attribute-table

I have a shapefile that draws up all 200 districts in a country. I want to select and colour 100 of these that I have on my list.

What would be the simplest way of going about this rather than me going through and selecting each one individually?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @JohnGriffin! How do you want to select the 100 features? By their location or do they have specific attributes?

Comment: Just by name, thanks Joseph!

Comment: And sorry to clarify one of the attributes lists each district's name.

Comment: Is there a common attribute shared between groups of districts? Also, if you just want to colour different districts, you could use a _Categorized_ symbology style and select the field with the names. Then manually remove the districts you are not interested in.

Comment: Unfortunately none, in the end I just created another attribute and marked each one I was interested in then categorized. Was hoping to avoid individually selecting each and use the list to do just perform some sort of matching or filter function. Again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of the names of the districts you want to select, you can do this with an expression:

```
"DistrictName" in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...)
```

Substitute the name of your district name column where that expression says `"DistrictName."` Substitute the actual district names from your list where it says `'name1'`, `'name2'`, etc.

There are two methods to use this expression:

1. Apply a [rule-based style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-renderer) to the district layer. Use the expression as the filter.
2. Use that expression in the `Select by expression` tool to select the features on your list. Create a new field, "Listed" using the Field Calculator, with this expression:

   ```
   is_selected()
   ```

   The "Listed" field will now read 1 for all the districts on your list. Apply a [categorized style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer) based on the new field.

   Now if you want, you can convert the categorized style to a rule-based style, and apply sub-categories within the `"Listed" = 1` rule, so that each district is a different color.